# SQL - Select where A is equal and B is variant

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this

```
mapname     id  time
---------------------
cvjourney   1   65.24
cvjourney   3   69.45
cvjourney   2   64.25
cvjourney   8   75.45
dark_hop    2   65.87
dark_hop    1   61.51
coldrunss   1   12.50
```

I want to select data from that table to get something like this (for id 1, 2)

```
cvjourney   1   65.24
cvjourney   2   64.25
dark_hop    2   65.87
dark_hop    1   61.51
```

so I want select data where two players are both having records on same map, I dont want select maps where player[1] has record and player[2] doesnt, or the other way.

Here is my select, but I cant get rid of maps where one player has record and another doesnt.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE mapname IN (
    SELECT mapname
    FROM table
    WHERE id IN ('1','2') 
) 
AND id IN ('1', '2') 
 ORDER BY mapname
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to get only those mapnames which have both the ids present (which means after applying the id filter, distinct count of ids will be two) and then use that to get the relevant rows.

```
select t1.*
from table t1
join (
    select mapname
    from table
    where id in (1, 2)
    group by mapname
    having count(distinct id) = 2
    ) t2 on t1.mapname = t2.mapname
where t1.id in (1, 2)
order by t1.mapname
```

Use can use `IN` too:

```
select t1.*
from table t1
where mapname in (
        select mapname
        from table
        where id in (1, 2)
        group by mapname
        having count(distinct id) = 2
        )
    and id in (1, 2)
order by mapname
```

### [Demo](http://rextester.com/CHPBZ5909)

Comment: thank you for answer, but it doesnt work, it returns 0 rows.

Comment: @TuF - It does. Please see the demo I added in the answer.